# if, else inside while

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have a `while` loop with the following code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<font size='2'>";


     echo "<table>";
     echo "<tr><th>Sender</th><th>Message</th></tr>";
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     echo "<tr><td style='width:15%;'>" . $row["sender"]. "</td><td style='width:100%;'>  " . $row["message"]. "</td>
     <td>
        <form action='?delete=" . $row["note_id"]. "' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='del_id' value='" . $row["note_id"]. "'/>
            <button type='submit' name='sell'><font size='1' color='blue'><img src='' height='9' width='9' title='Delete Message'/></font></button></form>

        <form action='?read=" . $row["note_id"]. "' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='read_id' value='" . $row["note_id"]. "'/>
            <button type='submit' name='sell'><font size='1' color='blue'><img src='' height='9' width='9' title='Mark as Read'/></font></button></form>
     </td>

     </tr><br>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
 echo "</font>";
} else {
 echo "No Messages!";
}
```

My question is... I want to show the second form button ONLY if a clause is met.
That button is a "Mark as Read" button and i only want to show it on the rows if that message is not marked as read already.
i tried a bunch of different aproaches but i guess i am missing the point.

If you could guide me in the right direction i would appreciate.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't leave us guessing which language this is ...

Comment: sorry bro, i forgot to mention it... it's php

Comment: And which property of `$row` tells if it's already read or not?

Comment: You should provide us with the fields available in your result set. Which is the field that has the info on whether a message is marked as "read". What values can it have?

Comment: one that is hidden from the table.
a sql row called "lida". I would prefer to keep it hidden from the common user

Comment: Yes, but you also hide it from us. Then you will have no answer. What is the name of that field? Data type? Which values can it have?

Comment: Not my intention. Its a int field that only states 1 or 0. 1 if the message is read, 0 if not

Comment: Basically if the question is "can I nest a *if* within a *while* scope", answer is yes.

Comment: @ringø can you please pick my code and edit it so it fit an _if_ inside? i tried with no success

Comment: This is not how it works - just look at @Shitiz Garg answer, that tells you how to do it. However, *parameter* is to be replaced with the "hidden" value ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to denote whether the post is marked as read or not?

You can have nested ifs inside of whiles (and so on so forth) like:

```
while ($row = function()) {
    if ($row['parameter']) {
        echo '';
    }
    echo '';
}
```

Comment: That was the cleanest way to do it i guess! THANK YOU ALL~

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<font size='2'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Sender</th><th>Message</th></tr>";
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     echo "<tr><td style='width:15%;'>" . $row["sender"]. "</td><td style='width:100%;'>  " . $row["message"]. "</td>
     <td>
        <form action='?delete=" . $row["note_id"]. "' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='del_id' value='" . $row["note_id"]. "'/>
            <button type='submit' name='sell'><font size='1' color='blue'><img src='' height='9' width='9' title='Delete Message'/></font></button></form>";

            // here is the code i added. close the echo of above and put `if` statement.

if($row["read"]!="yes"){ echo "
        <form action='?read=" . $row["note_id"]. "' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='read_id' value='" . $row["note_id"]. "'/>
            <button type='submit' name='sell'><font size='1' color='blue'><img src='' height='9' width='9' title='Mark as Read'/></font></button></form> ";
}   

// edit ends. again put another echo to continue your remaining code

echo "
     </td>

     </tr><br>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
 echo "</font>";
} else {
 echo "No Messages!";
}
```

Just change `$row["read"]!="yes"` to whatever you use to denote the message is read or not.

I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows, indeed with an `if`, but interrupt your `echo` for that, like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td style='width:15%;'>" . $row["sender"]. 
         "</td><td style='width:100%;'>  " . $row["message"]. "</td>
    <td>
        <form action='?delete=" . $row["note_id"]. "' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='del_id' value='" . $row["note_id"]. "'/>
            <button type='submit' name='sell'>
                <font size='1' color='blue'>
                    <img src='' height='9' width='9' title='Delete Message'/>
                </font>
            </button>
        </form>";
    if ($row['lida'] == 0) {                    
        echo "      
        <form action='?read=" . $row["note_id"]. "' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='read_id' value='" . $row["note_id"]. "'/>
            <button type='submit' name='sell'>
                <font size='1' color='blue'>
                    <img src='' height='9' width='9' title='Mark as Read'/>
                </font>
            </button>
        </form>";
    }
    echo "
    </td>
    </tr>";
}
```

NB: you should not add a `<br>` after a `</tr>`, that should happen after the `</table>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to maintain code, if HTML and php is not separated.
See my solution how they are separated.

You should replace `$condition` with your actual condition.

```
<?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) : ?>
<font size='2'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Sender</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>

    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td style='width:15%;'> <?php echo $row["sender"]; ?></td>
        <td style='width:100%;'> <?php echo $row["message"]; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php if($condition): ?>
            <form action='?delete=<?php echo $row["note_id"]; ?>' method='post'>
                <input type='hidden' name='del_id' value='<?php echo $row["note_id"]; ?>'/>
                <button type='submit' name='sell'>
                    <font size='1' color='blue'><img src='' height='9' width='9' title='Delete Message'/></font>
                </button>
            </form>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(!$condition): ?>
            <form action='?read=<?php echo $row["note_id"]; ?>' method='post'>
                <input type='hidden' name='read_id' value='<?php echo $row["note_id"]; ?>'/>
                <button type='submit' name='sell'>
                    <font size='1' color='blue'><img src='' height='9' width='9' title='Mark as Read'/></font>
                </button>
            </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
</font>

<?php else: ?>
No Messages!
<?php endif; ?>
```